Coding a Delete DML that doesn't get flagged for CRUD checking by code scanner
I can do an update this way and it pass the scanner --
SObjectAccessDecision securityDecision = Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.UPDATABLE, sObjectList);
update securityDecision.getRecords();

I believe it passes because the update statement is on the securityDescision.getRecords().  But you can't do that for delete.
I'm trying the following for delete --
if (Schema.Event.getSObjectType().getDescribe().isDeletable()) {
    delete eventList;
}

That gets flagged for the violation.  I guess the scanner isn't smart enough to follow the logic and the delete is not in the same statement as the check.
The technique I'm attempt is out of the doc -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_perms_enforcing.htm

Looks like a false positive due to a missing rule or that the eventList type does not allow the relevant rule to be applied...?
